# Create a table with array column ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I use ms sql and i need to create a table with a array column of nvarchar. What is the correct query ?

Comment: Not possible. SQL Server does not support arrays - but that's a bad idea to begin with. Why don't you properly normalize your data model?

Comment: Ttere are no array columns. In SQL, the language, fields should contain *single* values. It could be a single *complex* value like a coordinate but it's still a single value that's treated as one item. Even in databases that have arrays, like Oracle, they are treated as a single item and their contents can't be *queried* individually. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i need to create a table that contanis so many column, but 60 of that are similar and i want to insert that into an array. There is a limit for the column of a table?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: actually the SQL standard **does** define arrays (and Oracle does not have arrays as a datatype in SQL, only in PL/SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle allows storing arrays at least since Oracle 8i. I've used those features when working for a client that wanted spatial features without paying extra. Fun fact, Oracle 8i had a critical bug which would prevent you from reading *any* data once you went past an undetermined data size. Of course, the KB and fix was behind and NDA ...

Comment: I have a table for saving car date. For each car i want to save 60 accessories and 50 optionals. For this reason i want to save that into a two array but is not possibile. What is the best solution for doing that ?

Comment: @AttilioIurlaro: you need additional tables to store the one-to-many relationships. Please read up on database normalization

Comment: @AttilioIurlaro those aren't a lot of columns. Do you need to filter by those columns? Index them? Then they should be separate columns, no matter the database. You *won't* save *any* space by using an array of .... what? Each attribute is a *different* type of data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Oracle's nested tables are something different than arrays (at least from the perspective of the SQL standard - but that is completely off-topic now)

Comment: I second @a_horse_with_no_name, store those values in a separate table (N:1) to original table. You can easily aggregate them as a single value and have all sql search features available simultaniously..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the type of the data are the same

Comment: @AttilioIurlaro same what? I doubt any char has 50 colors or 50 ash trays. The type of data is *not* the same as the field's type. Just as you can't use aquamarine to light a cigarette or charge a phone, you can't store them in the same field. If you *don't* intend to filter by those fields *and* always intend to load all of them, you could use one or more JSON fields to store the extra data as JSON. Even then the attributes should be descriptive, eg `{ 'color':'aquamarine', 'rear_ashtray':'yes'}`

Comment: @AttilioIurlaro the problem you describe though is far more complex than `50 optional fields`. One option may have its own parts and options. That's a Bill of Materials which is easier to model in a graph database. In SQL Server hierarchical structures are often used to model a part composed of other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want an array column.  You want a separate table (or perhaps a JSON/XML column, but I won't focus on that).

The normal method would be:

```
create table main (
    main_id int identity primary key,
    . . .
);

create table element (
    element_id int identity primary key,
    position int,
    value varchar(255),
    . . .
);

create table main_elements (
    main_element_id int identity primary key,
    main_id int references main(main_id),
    element_id int references elements(element_id)
);
```